# Alter character varying column's length in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have table in production which has column type `character varying(255);`

All rows has entry in that column no longer than 15 characters and never will be larger as well. I decide to reduce its size to 15 characters with following command which I found on sof:

`ALTER TABLE user_template ALTER COLUMN "TYPE" character varying(15);`

I got following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "character"
LINE 1: ...LTER TABLE user_template ALTER COLUMN "type" character ...
                                                        ^
```

Can you help me to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the column name?

Comment: type, its in quotes because of type is reserved key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> create table user_template (field1 varchar(255));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE user_template ALTER COLUMN field1 TYPE varchar(15);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=40f8bd4ca9c9d4cb599183668478b085)*